# Looking for a mic set up for zoom in a large room

Tags: microphone, gear, zoom

I have used with success 4 boundary mics around a table. Now with more people in the room I am unable to pick up people away from the table and thought to add a condenser mic on a stand.

What kind of interface would allow boundary mics and a 48v condenser mic to connect to my laptop and work with zoom?

Is this even the best approach to my problem?

Comment: A mixer with more inputs will allow you to add more mics, whether they are additional boundary mics or condenser mics.

Comment: Thanks, I've been looking at the Yamaha AG03 or 06

Comment: Regarding the above Yamaha, does anyone know if I can have both a 48v XLR mic and a 5v boundary mics both plugged in and loop backed to my computer or does only one dominate at a time?

Comment: I've called Sweetwater and the engineer says with an AG06, I could plug in the bpundary mics which would be on channel one and the xlr on channel 2-3. So, I think that solves my problem